# Group by in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to power bi, i have my data like -

| dept. | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| application & int | 28 | 3088 |
| Business oper. | 17 | 2912 |
| application & int | 12 | 765 |
| Business oper. | 43 | 5449 |

I need to calculate group by of dept and then calculate sum of value 1 divided by sum of value 2
My output table should look like-

| dept. | cal_value |
| --- | --- |
| application & int | 0.01 |
| Business oper. | 0.007 |

please help me to get this output

Answer (score 1):

Just [write a measure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-tutorial-create-measures#:%7E:text=To%20see%20how%20Power%20BI%20Desktop%20creates%20a,SalesAmount%20onto%20the%20report%20canvas.%20%20See%20More.) for `cal_value` and the Power BI visuals will take care of the grouping.  IE when you add `dept` and `cal_value` to a table, you'll get your desired result.

Comment: Sir thanks for your reply, so SUM(table[value1])/SUM(table[value2]) inside a measure will work?

Comment: Yep.  Although we often use the DIVIDE function, as it doesn't produce divide-by-zero errors.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/divide-function-dax